# How do I set the minimum size of a Gtk ButtonBox child?

Tags: python-3.x, gtk, gtk3

[image: pic]

I'm trying to set the minimum size of the buttons in this GtkButtonBox.  Currently they seem to be fixed - approx 85 pixels I think.

Is this possible?

If not, is there another way in Gtk to get two small sized buttons to snuggle together like in the above picture rather than having them appear to be two separate buttons? For example GtkStackSwitcher may be something I could use but there doesn't appear to be a way to respond to click events for a button.

I've used this test program to create the above (Ubuntu 14.04, Gtk+3.10 and Python3):

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
import sys


class MyWindow(Gtk.ApplicationWindow):

    def __init__(self, app):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="example", application=app)
        self.set_default_size(350, 200)
        self.set_border_width(10)

        hbox = Gtk.ButtonBox.new(Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL)
        hbox.set_layout(Gtk.ButtonBoxStyle.EXPAND)
        button = Gtk.Button(label="a")
        hbox.add(button)
        button2 = Gtk.Button(label="b")
        hbox.add(button2)

        self.add(hbox)

class MyApplication(Gtk.Application):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Application.__init__(self)

    def do_activate(self):
        win = MyWindow(self)
        win.show_all()

    def do_startup(self):
        Gtk.Application.do_startup(self)

app = MyApplication()
exit_status = app.run(sys.argv)
sys.exit(exit_status)
```

---

With regards to a question about the desktop environment I'm using.

I've tried Mate, Unity and Gnome-Shell.  All work the same way.  I've removed the title and those controls.  Still the same thing happens. To me this looks more like a GTK issue.

Comment: I have a feeling it's your window manager not letting you resize the window to be smaller than necessary to fit the title and minimize/maximize/close buttons on the titlebar. What DE are you using?

Comment: @andlabs - thanks for the reply.  I've tried Mate, Unity and Gnome-Shell.  All work the same way.  I've removed the title and those controls.  Still the same thing.  Looks more like a GTK issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that `GtkButtonBox` imposes some layout constraints on its buttons that you may not want here. Try using buttons in just a regular `GtkGrid`, but give them the `GTK_STYLE_CLASS_LINKED` CSS class.

For each button, do:

```
button.get_style_context().add_class(Gtk.STYLE_CLASS_LINKED)
```

Comment: Hi - thanks for the reply - please could you point me in the right direction as to how I would apply "GTK_STYLE_CLASS_LINKED" to two or more buttons?